# Do I have to make getter setters for each element of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, getter, setter

My array is an array of objects. I only have one getter which returns the whole array.  However, if I want to modify the fields of the array elements in another class, I cannot do it through the array getter. The only solutions so far I have found is to either not leave the array field private or make getter/setter methods for each element of the array. Is there a better way to do this?

For context, the the array is an array of Points. each point has a x coordinate and y coordinate

when I do `Line.getPoints().getX()`, for example, it doesn't work.
`Line.points[1].getX()` works but only if don't keep the array private.

Comment: Have you tried: `setArray (Object[] array)` and `setElement (int index, Object element)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a public getter and do something like getPoints()[1].getX()
or getPoints()[1].setLocation(2,3)

Comment: He wants to set an element in the array (e.g. `array[1]`) to a value (e.g. `array[1] = new Object();`)

Comment: @EldarB. His question was not about changing the object of the array at a certain position. He wanted to know how to change the fields of an object at a certain position.
And he didn't know he could use the '[x]' notation after a getter which returns an array.